# A paper claiming that optimization version of symmetric TSP can be solved in polynomial time

Tags: optimization, complexity-classes, polynomial-time, traveling-salesman

In the following [paper](https://doi.org/10.4236/ajcm.2019.92005) : 
Czopik, J. (2019) An Application of the Hungarian Algorithm to Solve Traveling Salesman Problem. American Journal of Computational Mathematics,9, 61-67.

In the Introduction, the author claims that the problem is NP-hard. They proceed to give a exact solution in polynomial time.

[image]

My problem is that if we can solve TSP optimization in polynomial time, we can also solve the decision version of TSP, which is NP-complete in polynomial time.

The TSP decision problem asks that given the costs and a number $x$, decide whether there is a round-trip route cheaper than $x$. let us denote $min_x$ as the smallest path that satisfies our conditions. we can find min_x from the above claim in polynomial time. Then if $x > min_x$, the answer is Yes else No. Thus, the decision problem can be solved in polynomial time.

But TSP-decision belongs to NP-complete and thus there cannot be a polynomial time solution. Where am I getting things wrong?

Comment: I haven't gone over the paper carefully, but this is obviously not a proper paper, hasn't been peer-reviewed, and doesn't have any correctness arguments. I wouldn't be surprised to find that the algorithm is simply incorrect, as opposed to merely not running in polynomial time, or not giving any bounded approximation ratio.

Comment: It has been published in American Journal of Computational Mathematics which [claims](https://publons.com/journal/21364/american-journal-of-computational-mathematics/) its articles are peer reviewed. Thank you for your observation.

Comment: The entire publisher seems to be a scam (even if it self-claims to be peer reviewed):https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Research_Publishing
Also, note that the paper is riddled with typos. If it has undergone peer review, it isn't a very good one...

Comment: I have a hard time believing any proper peer-review would accept a paper which cites Wikipedia (especially without revision tags --- therefore not future proofed against edits!) as a source.

Comment: I was missing too many red flags. Thanks again.

Comment: Obviously bad English grammar doesn't mean the results are wrong - but I'd estimate the chances of a polynomial time algorithm for an NP-complete problem to be less than one in a billion, and the chances of a faulty paper at least a million times higher.

Comment: The genius author claims to have polynomial algorithm for TSP using Hungarian algorithm. First, he presents the naive version of the Hungarian alrogithm ($O(n^4)$) instead of the dual one in $O(n^3)$... Finally to treat the cycles, he forbids one edge of the cycle (kind of random one, it's quite unclear, to cite author: "The cycle appears if the solution contains pair of elements (i, k) and
(l, i) diﬀerent of 0 and i != 1"). Of course, it is wrong, one cannot prove that the forbidden edge is not part of the optimal solution.

Comment: @Optidad Could you make a full answer out of that? You'd have my upvote. I find dissections of faulty proofs interesting.

Comment: @kviiri I would really like to but I feel too unconfortable with the sentence I cited. I cannot get what author thinks he is doing, even if I am pretty sure the mistake is here.